# In javascript if block executes even the result is false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have the below funtion in aspx page javascript:

```
function checkID(source, arguments) {
        if (!document.getElementById('lstAID').isDisabled) {
            if (parseInt(document.getElementById('hidID').value) > 0) {
                arguments.IsValid = true;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('lstApID_HiddenField') != null
                && document.getElementById('lstApID_HiddenField') !== undefined
                && parseInt(document.getElementById('lstApID_HiddenField').value) > 0) {

                arguments.IsValid = true;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('lstApID_TextBox') != null
                && document.getElementById('lstApID_TextBox') !== undefined
                && document.getElementById('lstApID_TextBox').innerText.trim().value !== "(Select Cost Approver)") {

                arguments.IsValid = true;
            }

            else {

                arguments.IsValid = false;
            }
            
        }
  }
```

The line parseInt(document.getElementById('hidID').value) > 0 executes to false when hidID has 0 which is correct. But it still control goes into first if block and executes the first if block makes arguments true.
I have no clue, have been trying, could someone advise ?

Thanks

I have tried altering the if blocks but always it goes into first if block even if it is false.

@Jake,
The control is AjaxControlToolkit combobox as DropdownList has customvalidation and calls the above function checkID(s, a). Based on login it gets populated with different names. sometimes dropdown has autopopulated value and sometimes no. we need to make sure that this field is selected some approver before moving further. The control is rendered differently in all the scenarios and checking one by one field where are value is avalaible. In this case, it has (select approver) text displayed and 0 in hidden field , so it should ask to select approver but not asking ..in the first block it is making it true (eventhough if block is false) and making arguments true and postback null reference exception.

Comment: how do you know its false? did you try debugging in the browser console or debugger?

Comment: Your second and third blocks also set `arguments.IsValid` to true.  Can you provide a complete example so that we can run the code and see the bug you're describing?

Comment: debugger, i have also enabled script debugging vs studio debugging, i have put break point , that way also im debugging;

Comment: @jake , updared question.

Comment: Hmmmm the additional context is probably useful, but I meant as a StackSnippet, JSFiddle, CodeSandbox, or other similar tool.  Something where we can get a complete picture of your code and actually *run* it ourselves to reproduce the problem.